# displaying live feeds : dailybooth live feed, twitter search result stream

Tags: rss, live, feed, twitter-feed

What is the web technology behind displaying live feeds like twitter search results and [dailybooth live feed](http://dailybooth.com/live)? Can I get similar results from any RSS with some coding?

Answer (score 0):

The main technology behind such websites often is [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). This is used to dynamically change the webpages instead of reloading the whole page.

Comment: Specifically I would like to know what makes it live so that we get the results without doing any action on the page.. let's take twitter: when you search for a word you get results then on the top it is still getting new results and tells you that new results are received..Can this be done for example for CNN rss subscription? for twitter I couldnt display json callback without refreshing the page..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! You will probably need a realtime ([PubSubHubbub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PubSubHubbub)-enabled feed) to achieve this, and plug it into some kind of websocket/comet/ajax/longpolling client... but that should work easily. [Check this](http://julien51.github.com/socket-sub/maps), for example. It's the firehose of gowalla checkins posted to a google map. All the code is on github, so it's quite easy to build, play with!